# How do I use colgroup in HTML / CSS for better formatting Tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I got a Problem with the Tables on my HTML Page. [How my Table looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRL9S.png)
I'm trying to restrict the columns to a special value so that the Time column is smaller than the rest of the weekday columns.

```
<main>
        <h1>Stundenplan 6. Semester iING</h1></br>
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="7">Studiengang Mechatronik</br>
                            6. Semester, Sommersemester 2023
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <colgroup width="1*">
                    <colgroup span="5" width="5*">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Montag</th>
                        <th>Dienstag</th>
                        <th>Mittwoch</th>
                        <th>Donnerstag</th>
                        <th>Freitag</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Time -->
                        <td>08:15</td>
                        <!-- Mo -->
                        <td rowspan="2">VL Produktionstechnik</td>
                        <!-- Di -->
                        <td rowspan="2">PR Computer & Networking</td>
                        <!-- Mi -->
                        <td rowspan="7">VL Sensorik & Bussysteme</td>
                        <!-- Do -->
                        <td></td>
                        <!-- Fr -->
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
...
...
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>
```

I made my whole page grid orientated but the main part with flex, because I thought I could arrange some parts easier with that....

I searched a lot about arranging an HTML page and I found a lot of different ways, how some had ached well-structured pages. But I could not find the best practices...
For arranging Tables I got a lot more confused...
Also for structuring the table, I found some explanations, but I could not get it to work. [See Chapter 11.2.4 Column groups](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3)

1. Is my whole Table messed up?
2. How do I use `colgroup` right?

Edit:
The requirements for the table to pass are

- more than 10 cells
- one cell should span over all others with the title
- Every column should have a th

Comment: You linked to the HTML4 specification which has a big banner on the side saying "Superseded" (not to mention now **being 24 years old**, yegods) - you should only use the current HTML "Living Specification" document instead: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/

Comment: `<colgroup>` is documented here btw: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-colgroup-element

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you should correct that first - for example, `</br>` should be `<br />` or `<br>` - and you shouldn't use `<thead><tr><th colspan="7">` for a table title: use `<table><caption>Title goes here</caption>` for that.

Comment: Secondly, `<colgroup>` is a child of `<table>` and not `<tbody>` and colgroup elements must appear _before_ any `<thead>` or `<tbody>` elements - and there is no `width=""` attribute on `<colgroup>` in the current HTML specification.

Comment: So is there a way to specify how big a column should be?

Comment: What do you mean by “specify how big”, exactly?

Comment: @Dai The first column is quite big for only the time and the Friday column got squished too much for my liking. I would achieve a small Time column and a consistently throw the Day columns.

Comment: Use `table-layout: fixed;` and set explicit `width:` values on the first (top) cell in each column. Personally I advocate that people should use `em` for element sizing that follows text sizes, but there’s nothing wrong with using `px` either. You can use `%` too but be careful.

Comment: @Dai thx, now it works. I also figured out that I used in the CSS table `width="100%"` which seemed like it rendered the width setting for each column useless. 
I hoped to archive a `%` regulated width where the table is set to `100%` of my `main width`. And from there on I could regulate like `<th width="10%">Time</th>` and the rest to `<th width="18%"></th>`... 

It works but without the table width set. No clue why.

Comment: Please don’t use the deprecated `width=` attribute, Use _only_ CSS properties.